# Mathematical notation - cummulative summation

Tags: notation

The Mertens function can be calculated in *Mathematica* by:

```
Accumulate[Table[MoebiusMu[k], {k, 1, n}]]
```

and is written as $$M(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n\mu(k)$$

Could someone please tell me how I would write

```
Table[Mean[Accumulate[Table[MoebiusMu[k], {k, 1, n}]]], {n, 1, x}]
```

in mathematical notation?

Comment: Perhaps this is better asked on MathematicaStackExchange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how `Accumulate` works: `Accumulate[{a, b, c, d}]` produces

```
{a, a + b, a + b + c, a + b + c + d}
```

Thus, the `m`th entry of the list `Accumulate[Table[MoebiusMu[k], {k, 1, n}]]` is
$$M(m)=\sum_{k=1}^m\mu(k)$$
so that `Mean[Accumulate[Table[MoebiusMu[k], {k, 1, n}]]]`, the average of the `n` entries on this list, is the just average of the first $n$ values of the Mertens function $M(k)$:
$$\frac{1}{n}\left(\sum_{k=1}^nM(k)\right)\qquad$$
and then the outer `Table` just makes a list of these values from `n=1` to `n=x`.

Comment: Thank you - this is really clear and helpful!